# Different answers for same integral.

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, change-of-variable

Let, $x = \cos(\theta)$ and

$$s = \int^{1}_{-1}\frac{1 \ dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}.$$

If we let $1 = \cos(2\pi)$ and $-1 = \cos(\pi)$, we obtain:
$$s = -\int^{2\pi}_{\pi}1 dx  = -\pi.$$

However, if we let $1 = \cos(0)$ and $-1 = \cos(\pi)$, we obtain:
$$s = -\int^{0}_{\pi}1 dx = \pi.$$

Comment: Square root always returns a positive number. Did you check whether to use $\sqrt{\sin^2\theta} = \sin\theta$ or $\sqrt{\sin^2\theta}=-\sin\theta$ for each of those substitutions?

Comment: Yes, the negative sign comes the fact that $\frac{dx}{d\theta}  = -\sin(\theta)$

Comment: I think you didn't understand the point of my comment. Let me ask you a different question, is $(-\sin\theta)$ a positive or a negative number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your substitution requires the use of the inverse cosine function in the transformed limits [ $ \theta \ = \ \arccos(x) \ $ ] .  So $ \ \arccos(1) \ = \ 0 \ $ and $ \ \arccos(-1) \ = \ \pi \ $ , making your second definite integral the correct one.